# Enable CSRF TOKEN in Django html coded using element-ui

Tags: html, django, csrf, element-ui, csrf-token

I am trying to add CSRF TOKEN in my html script (Django framework) for ensure CSRF protection so that my POST requests will be be classified as an unsafe request.
However I am unsure of where I should place it. When I place it within {% verbatim %}, it comes off as a text as shown on in the image.

Really desperate and really appreciate any advice.

```
{%extends "doctor.html" %}

{% block emr %}active{% endblock %}

{% block mainbody %}

{% verbatim %}
{% csrf_token %}

<div id="app2" class="container">
  <el-row :gutter="20" style="width: 90%; height: 120%;">
    <el-col :span="12">
      <div class="info-wrapper">
        <div class="header">Add new medication delivery jobs</div>
        <el-form ref="deliveryInfoForm" :model="deliveryInfo" :rules="deliveryRules" label-width="110px" label-position="left">
          <el-form-item label="Order ID" prop="order_id">
            <el-select v-model="deliveryInfo.order_id" placeholder="Select an Order ID" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 0px;" >
              <el-option
              v-for="item in order_id"
              :key="item.id"  
              :label="item.order_id"
              :value="item.order_id">
              <span style="float: left">{{ item.order_id }}</span>
            </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>

          <el-form-item label="Box Number" prop="box_number">
            <el-select v-model="deliveryInfo.box_number" placeholder="Default: Box 1" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 0px;" >
              <el-option
              v-for="item in box_options"
              :key="item.value"
              :label="item.label"
              :value="item.value">
              <span style="float: left">{{ item.label }}</span>
            </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>

          <el-form-item>
            <el-button style="width: 100%;" type="primary" @click="onSubmit">Confirm</el-button> 
          </el-form-item>
        </el-form>
      </div>
    </el-col>

    <el-col :span="12">
      <div class="info-wrapper">
        <div class="header"><center>Medications Delivery Status</center></div>
        <el-table
          :data="list"
          stripe
          style="width: 100%"
          :cell-style="{ textAlign: 'left' }"        
            :header-cell-style="{textAlign: 'left'}">
          <el-table-column
            prop="job_id"
            label="Job ID"
            width="120">
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column
            prop="order_id"
            label="Order ID"
            width="150">
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column
            prop="ward_number"
            label="Ward No."
            width="80">
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column
            prop="status"
            label="Status"
            width="90">
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column
            prop="recorded_date"
            label="Date Assigned"
            width="110">
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column
            prop="recorded_time"
            label="Time Assigned"
            width="110">
          </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
      </div>
    </el-col>
    
  </el-row>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}



<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app2',
    data() {
      return {
        list: [],
        addDeliveryFormType: 1,
        userInfo: {
          user_id: '',
          patient_id: ''
        },

        deliveryInfo: {
          order_id: '',
          ward_number: '',
        },
        
        deliveryRules: {
          order_id: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter select the Order ID', trigger: 'blur' }],
          box_number: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select a box number', trigger: 'blur' }],
        },

        box_options: [{
          value: '1',
          label: 'Box 1'
        }, {
          value: '2',
          label: 'Box 2'
        }, {
          value: '3',
          label: 'Box 3'
        }, {
          value: '4',
          label: 'Box 4'
        }, {
          value: '5',
          label: 'Box 5'
        }, {
          value: '6',
          label: 'Box 6'
        }, {
          value: '7',
          label: 'Box 7'
        }],

        order_id: []

      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.getDeliveryList() // A function in methods. Purpose: To get the list of uncompleted medications delivery statuses
      this.getOrderIDList()
    },

    methods: {
      getOrderIDList() {

        axios.post(ToDJ('OrderIDList'), new URLSearchParams()).then(res => {
          if (res.data.code === 0) {
            this.order_id = res.data.data
          } else {
            this.NotifyFail(res.data.data)
          }
        })
      },

      // To track the delivery of medications that is not completed
      getDeliveryList() {
        axios.post(ToDJ("deliveryList"), new URLSearchParams()).then(res => {
          if (res.data.code === 0) {
            this.list = res.data.data
          } else {
            this.NotifyFail(res.data.data)
          }
        })
      },

      // Once SUBMIT BUTTON is pressed
      onSubmit() {
        this.$refs.deliveryInfoForm.validate((valid) => {
          if (valid) {
            if (this.addDeliveryFormType === 1) {
              axios.post(ToDJ('deliveryJob'), new URLSearchParams(this.deliveryInfo)).then(res => {
                if (res.data.code === 0) {
                  this.NotifySuc("Job Sumitted!")
                  this.deliveryInfoForm = true
                  Object.assign(this.deliveryInfo, this.$options.data().deliveryInfo)
                  this.getDeliveryList()
                  this.getOrderIDList()
                } else {
                  this.NotifyFail(res.data.data)
                  Object.assign(this.deliveryInfo, this.$options.data().deliveryInfo)
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      },

      // Success Notification
      NotifySuc(str) {
        this.$message({
          message: str,
          type: 'success'
        })
            },
      // Error Notification
            NotifyFail(str) {
        this.$message({
          message: str,
          type: 'warning'
        })
            },
      // Format time
      formateTime(oriDate) {
        if (!oriDate) {
          return ''
        }
        const formateDate = new Date(oriDate)
        const year =  formateDate.getFullYear()
        const month =  formateDate.getMonth() + 1
        const day = formateDate.getDate()
        let h = formateDate.getHours()
        let m = formateDate.getMinutes()
        let s = formateDate.getSeconds()
        h = h >= 10 ? h : `0${h}`
        m = m >= 10 ? m : `0${m}`
        s = s >= 10 ? s : `0${s}`
        return `${year}-${month}-${day} ${h}:${m}`
      }
    }
  })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start the `{% verbatim %}` *after the CSRF token:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% verbatim %}
    ...
{% endverbatim %}
```